# Diff and Patch for multiple files

Tags: diff, patch

I'm new to linux and bash so I'm sorry if my question will be stupid, but I have problem with creating and applying patch file.

Lets say I have two directories **original/** and **new/** and in the original directory are few files like 4 or 5 that are either completly missing in **new/** or are changed and some of them are in some subdirectories.

According to some tutorial I shoud use `diff -rubN original/ new/ > patch.diff` but other tutorials state the opposite that i sohold use `diff -rubN new/ original/ > patch.diff`

Anyway if I use the first one and then run `patch -t -p0 < patch.diff` strange thing happens, I get results "patching file original/subfolder/filename" for all files and then the **original/** folder dissapear, the **new/** folder is still empty and I have to run the patch command again. When I do I get messages "The next patch would delete the file new/subfolder/filename, which does not exist!" - after this there are files in **new/** folder, which is fine, but I dont know:

- why was the **original/** folder deleted
- why I have to run the patch command twice to get the files to the **new/** folder
- why the patch gives me message that the file doesn not exist when they do?

Edit: if it is not clear from the text, I am trying to transfer changes that are in the files in the **original/** folder to the **new/** folder. Seems that the second diff (`diff -rubN new/ original/ > patch.diff`) is working for this case and for one file only as it should... but as soon as the diff is for more than one file, for example if I add new file to the **original/** folder, that doesnt exist in **new/** folder, the patch ends with those strange way, deleting the file that is not in the **new/** folder and print message that "The next patch would create the file ../path to the original file/.. which already exists!" and "patching file ../path to the original file"

Also one new observation, after first patch commend only files that dont exist in the **new/** folder seems to be deleetd from the **original/** folder

**Edit2:** Ok, just find out that if i use `cd new/; patch -p1 < ../patch.diff` the patch ends OK and the **original/** folder is not deleted. **I just didnt get why** because to me ot seems to be same code -> p0 from directory where /original and /new folders are OR p1 from /new directory .... I cant see the difference